# Pin or freeze or group the file in the top of specific folder win10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

Is there any way to pin a specific file on the top of a specific folder?

After searching, I still cant find if there is any way to pin a file in a folder. My requirement is when I open the specific folder for specific project information, I would like to instantly see my excel sheet for recording all important info in this project(I called it "master sheet excel file" below). But the folder still has many files and many excel sheets. It makes me hard to quickly find the "master sheet excel file", and enter my main task.

I recognize that I can use the search bar and input keywords to find the files, but as you may know, the windows file explorer searching function is slow. Sometimes I could search with my eyes quicker than it if there are not many files in the folder. For that reason, I wonder if there is a method to operate the action consistently?

Many thanks for any feedback on that.

Comment: You could use sort by name and add `_` to the front of master filename

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you! I caught what you mean. I think there is also a simple strategy to overcome this issue! Unfortunately, since I would also use Chinese to name another file, it would prior show files named by Chinese, but it still a good way to follow. Many thanks !